# IIS cookbook to install web site

Tags: chef-recipe

While running chef-client for AN IIS installation to install a new web site, I am getting this error: "Unable to find package iis_site." How does the iis_site resource work?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `depends "windows"` to your metadata.rb file
you also have to download windows cookbook and dependencies, and upload it to your org.

```
knife cookbook site download windows
knife cookbook upload windows
```

Using the depends "windows" will allow you to use various resources that come from the windows cookbook, including the IIS_SITE resource.